# Move last n commits from svn to git repo

Tags: git, svn

We have a git repo that was created from svn repo.

However, after a git repo was created, some stuff was committed into svn.

I can create a patch for each svn revision and import it to git, but that is time consuming.

What is the simplest way to move last n commits from svn to git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was the Git repository converted using `git svn`?

If yes, you just need `git svn fetch` followed by merging.

If no, one way to roll would be to convert the whole Subversion repository anew using `git svn`, then fetch the necessary branches from the resulting repository into your existing Git repository and `git cherry-pick` the necessary ranges of commits to the corresponding branches.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ git svn init <project url> --trunk=<path to trunk> local_repo
$ cd local_repo
$ git svn fetch --revision=X:HEAD # where X - last revision, that was already imported to git
$ cd ../your_actual_repo
$ git remote add tmp ../local_repo
$ git fetch --all
$ # cherry pick or rebase commits, that you want
  # from remotes/tmp/master to master, you probably
  # want to fix them afterwards with git rebase --interactive
$ git remote remove tmp
```